# Is there some way to not fold/enclose identical lines with go-cmp?

Tags: go

I'm using go-cmp to compare and show the diff between two structures.
It works great, but I would like to show the entire struct instead of only the changed lines.

For example: https://play.golang.org/p/ynqUE2jPC-7

What I want

```
  main.MyType{
    Field1: "A",
    Field2: "B",
    Field3: "C",
    Field4: "D",
    Field5: "E",
-   Field6: "F",
+   Field6: "G",
  }
```

What I have

```
  main.MyType{
    ... // 3 identical fields
    Field4: "D",
    Field5: "E",
-   Field6: "F",
+   Field6: "G",
  }
```

In the documentation I could not find such option, I also tried to check the code but it is too complex for my current Go knowledge.

Comment: Your title and your question don't match at all. No lines are wrapped in your output. And I highly doubt `go-cmp` does any line wrapping at all. That would be a function of your terminal, or whatever other mechanism you use to view a diff.

Comment: @Flimzy, sorry english is not my native language, what I  mean with wrap is something like this definition `cover or enclose in paper or soft material `

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help. There's no paper or soft material involved in `go-cmp`.